# Function that takes a list and returns a list with only unique elements from the original?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am working my way through the Think Python Textbook, and one of the problems it gives is to make a function that takes a list and returns a list with only unique elements from the original. What I have so far is this:

```
def remove_duplicates(l):
    index = 0
    new_l = []
    dup_l = []
    while index < len(l):
        if l[index] in l[index+1:] or l[index] in new_l:
            dup_l += [l[index]]
            index = index + 1
        elif l[index] in dup_l:
            index = index + 1
        else:
            new_l += [l[index]]
    return new_l
```

I feel like there must be a more succinct, pythonic way to write this function. Can somebody help this beginner programmer?

Comment: I duped you to the canonical post about returning a list with only unique elements that *preserves order*. If order doesn't matter, just use `return list(set(l))`.

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate because Jeremy seems to be asking of a way to do it manually, so I've added that answer. Marking as duplicate like may come up as not very new user friendly,

Comment: Thanks guys very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you **want to do it manually**, to understand python syntax so this is a way of doing it.

**Update** for the comment made about only getting elements that occur only once and not removing duplicates, you can replace the `if` condition to `if L.count(element) == 1:` and it will return `[1,2,4]` as you were requesting.

```
def unique(L):
    uniqueElements = []
    for element in L:
        if element not in uniqueElements:
            uniqueElements.append(element)
    return uniqueElements

print(unique([1,2,3,3,4]))
```

And if you want to delve further into the python syntax, you could do a [list comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) and simplify it further, while still not using the `set` method which loses the order of elements:

```
def unique(L): return [element for element in L if L.count(element) == 1]
```

Comment: Well, actually the problem I was trying to solve would make a list that would have returned

`print(unique([1,2,3,3,4])) --->  [1, 2, 4]`
This is because I want only unique elements from the input list, not just a list that deletes duplicates.

Also how is my comment formatting?

Comment: Replace the `if` condition to `if L.count(element) == 1:` do get `[1,2,4]`